# Lens shows docker-desktop disconnected

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Just downloaded Lens 5.25. Windows 10, Docker Desktop 4/v20.10.8, Kubernetes v1.21.4.

I run `Docker Desktop`, wait until `Kubernetes` is ready and then open `Lens`.

It shows `docker-desktop` as being disconnected[image].

There is no way to get past this screen. How do I open the `docker-desktop` cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the cluster to open its information panel, then select the connect (chainlink) icon in the toolbar.

[image]

You can then click the cluster's icon in the same panel to open it.